# Highchart - get number of legends disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I have created line chart using Highcharts. I have 4 series and thus it shows 4 legends. I need a functionality where I want to know if 3 legends have been disabled i.e. only 1 series data is there , then redraw the chart .Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you after a number telling you the total number of series and how many are active? Or do you just want to see what is currently active vs what is not, like: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-visible/ ?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want to achieve. You can disable visibility of the series, as in the example provided by @ewolden or do not show series in the legend at all by setting `showInLegend` property with false value (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.showInLegend).